# how to do any mathematical calculation on stitch..over column in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to calculate YoY growth on my raw data. By using stitch over(lead) I am able to get last year's data along with current year data. But I am not able to do any calculation on the column returned by stitch over () clause. Below is what I have tried so far,

```
grunt> data = LOAD 'loan_pig' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();  
grunt> grp1 = group data by issue_yr;  
grunt> tot_loan = foreach grp1{ cnt = COUNT(data.id); generate FLATTEN(group) as issue_yr,cnt as ln_cnt;};  
grunt> grp2 = group tot_loan all;  
grunt> loan_yr = foreach grp2{ srt = order tot_loan by issue_yr desc; generate FLATTEN(Stitch(srt, Over(srt.ln_cnt,'lead',0,1,1,0)));};  
grunt> final = foreach loan_yr generate issue_yr,ln_cnt,$2;  
grunt> describe final;
```

when I describe on final, it shows

```
final: {stitched::issue_yr: int,stitched::ln_cnt: long,NULL}
```

`NULL` for the 'lead' value column.
And when I try to do any mathematical calculation on this column it throws below error :

```
grunt> final1 = foreach loan_yr generate issue_yr,ln_cnt,$2 as pr_yr;  
grunt> fn = foreach final1 generate issue_yr,ln_cnt-pr_yr;
```

> 2016-06-24 11:23:42,118 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 1052: Cannot cast bytearray to long

Can any one please let me know if there is any way to do calculation with columns returned from Stitch...Over. Or are they even possible in pig?

Comment: Please format code using the {} button in the editor, or by indenting each line with four spaces.

Comment: I have found one solution for above. I need to define the return type of Over function as int, such as , 'define Over org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over(‘int’); '     . After this, it is working as a charm